# Recuperar dados do firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react

Estou criando uma aplicação com `react` e atualmente preciso recuperar alguns dados do `database` utilizando a biblioteca do `firebase`, para isso criei um módulo que realiza a configuração:

Arquivo: `firebase.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
    apiKey: "XYZ",
    authDomain: "XYZ.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://XYZ.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XYZ",
    storageBucket: "XYZ.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "123"
};

export default firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Dentro de outro módulo eu incluo o módulo de configuração e começo a utilizar:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import firebase from '../../firebase'

export default class MeuComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount () {
        console.log('did mount');
        var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('apiDataReference');
        dbRef.on('value', snap => console.log(snap.val()));
    }
 ...
}
```

Quando o componente é renderizado eu vejo o `did mount` usado no `console.log()`, porém recebo o seguinte erro em seguida:

> unreachable code after return statement [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Stmt_after_return)

Comment: Como é o método `render` desse componente?

Comment: é um formulário @Sergio

Comment: Algures no teu componente tens um return com código depois dele que não é usado, podes verificar isso?

Comment: Já verifiquei @Sergio, infelizmente descobri que este erro só acontece no firefox.